# Remove Windows XP after installation of Lubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, uninstall, windows-xp

So thanks to this excellent forum I've got Lubuntu installed alongside Windows XP on my old laptop. When I decide to completely remove XP, should I simply reinstall Lubuntu from my image file?  Or is there another way to remove the old XP system, that will preserve the updates I have downloaded to Lubuntu 15.04?

Comment: *15.04, just delete the partition of Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to run [GParted](http://gparted.org/) from a live CD/USB. This will allow you to safely remove the Windows partition and resize the Lubuntu one to fill the entire drive. As always, be sure to have any important files backed up to a separate media. If you need a step-by-step, [this How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/) should help.

It is possible that if the operation includes moving the start of the partition containing /boot that you may need to reinstall Grub2. There are several ways to do this. You could try using Boot-Repair (GUI) or grub-install (CLI) from the live media: [Guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/)

Comment: Thanks BattleDingo this sounds ideal.  I plan to do this soon.

Comment: There is no need to reinstall grub if start of `/boot` partition changes. This was an old requirement of the defunct ?) **lilo** bootloader.